# Directory not empty error: when archiving

Tags: xcode

Hello i have this error on xcode 13 when archiving:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TfmFW.png)

Error: remove /Users/user220464/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/POMME30-bkitvnomignrdubdjcnsrgrfenvu/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/POMME30/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/POMME30.app/1-POMME30: Directory not empty (in target 'POMME30' from project 'POMME30')

i'm beginner at xcode, how can i resolve This problme ?
Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

it's easy
i had to empty the specified folder